# my json give as output string and not int in python

Tags: python, json

```
import pathlib
a=pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
dirc=str(a)+'\\file.json'
dirc2=str(a)+'\\PrettyJson.json'
data={1: {"titolo": "yea boi", "voto": 10, "genere": "a me ne so"}, 2: {"titolo": "yea boi 2", "voto": 8, "genere": "bo"}}

def jsonPrettyPrint():
    with open(dirc,'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file)
    with open(dirc) as json_file:
        with open(dirc2,'w') as PrettyJsonFile:
            Obj = json.load(json_file)
            PrettyJson = json.dumps(Obj, indent=4)
            json.dump(PrettyJson,PrettyJsonFile)
            print(PrettyJson)

jsonPrettyPrint()
```

Here the code, it work properly, but when i print Pretty Json, it give as output this

```
{
    "1": {
        "titolo": "yea boi",
        "voto": 10,
        "genere": "a me ne so"
    },
    "2": {
        "titolo": "yea boi 2",
        "voto": 8,
        "genere": "bo"
    }
}
```

as u can see, 2 and 1 are strings and not intengers, but 8 and 10 are intengers, idk why, any help would be appreciated

Comment: JSON keys __must__ be strings. That's the only allowed type according to the [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

Comment: JSON keys can only be **strings**. Therefore `1` and `2` are strings.

Comment: oh thanks... but i need keys to be intengers in some way, how i can?

Comment: Don't use JSON. Use something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the keys to int after loading the JSON.

```
with open(dirc) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
for key, value in list(data.items()):
    data[int(key)] = value
    del data[key]
print(data)
```

Comment: oh thanks i was trying to do this, but now
```
File "c:/Users/giuse/OneDrive/Desktop/Anime List/jsonHandler.py", line 21, in <module>
    for key, value in data.items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: Use `list(data.items())` to extract everything into a list first.